# After click listview to display data

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

i have a listview which display 4 items ( id, type, location & price). im trying to display more items after click the certain item in the listview.

**this is my table**

`static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 = "create table "+data+
         "( " +data_id+" integer primary key autoincrement,"
         + "TITLE text,TYPE  text,LOCATION text, PRICE text, ADDRESS text, DESCRIPTION text); ";`

**below is the listview**

```
listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);
  mySQLadapter = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
  mySQLadapter.openToWrite();
  cursor = mySQLadapter.queueAll5();


  String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseAdapter.data_id,DatabaseAdapter.type, DatabaseAdapter.location,DatabaseAdapter.price};
  int[] to = new int[]{R.id.getId2,R.id.getType,R.id.getLocation,R.id.getPrice};

  cursorAdapter =
   new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.roomdetails_list2, cursor, from, to);
  listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

for example, in the table, a set of data have been stored.

```
id 1, title halo, type condo, location kl, price 200, address bukit bintang, description good
```

on the listview only display id,type,location,price. But now i wan to click on it n display whole row on the next activity. what should i do with the query? how is the condition?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that once you click on a row. A new activity starts and it had all the information about the `row`

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vmf_items_list);   
list.setOnItemClickListener(LstListener);

private OnItemClickListener LstListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Object ob= list.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Log.i(Tag, "DisplayID:" + ob.toString());
        //calling the next activity 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("DisplayID", o.get(KEY_SVBID));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```